# Vue.js won't bind to an object property that's not pre-defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dynamic table generated on the server-side. Each row of the table is associated with an ID. Every row has a button. My goal is simple: when the user clicks a button in a row, that particular button should change to the 'is-loading' class and an AJAX call should fire. When the AJAX call resolves, the button should change to the 'is-success' class.

I could do this easily in jQuery, but I'm trying to learn Vue.js for this project. When I try to think about this from a Vue perspective, I'm effectively saying that the state of each row is changing first to a "loading" state and then to a "success" state. So if I have a `rowState` object, I can change the value of `rowState[rowID]` to change the state of the button, and bind my button's class to the value of `rowState[rowID]`. For example, for row #2 of the table, my button might look like:

```
<button :class="[{ 'is-loading': (rowState[2] == 1) }, {'is-success': (rowState[2] == 2) }]" @click="changeRowState(2)">
```

Then the `changeRowState` method would look like:

```
changeRowState(rowID) {
    this.rowState[rowID] = 1;
}
```

This works fine (i.e. it adds the 'is-loading' class to the button in row #2 when it's clicked) if I define `rowState` in Vue like this:

```
data: {
    rowState: {2: 0},
}
```

However, it fails if I don't pre-populate rowState with a list of all the possible row IDs. If there is no `2` property when `rowState` is created, adding that property later does not work.

```
data: {
    rowState: {},
}
```

I can't see any practical way to add a property for every row in this dynamically generated table into the initial definition. Am I missing something obvious? I'm reasonably familiar with JS but very new to Vue.

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/wn28myvh/47/). If you change the `rowState` definition to `{2: 0}`, it works (the button turns red when clicked). If the `2` property is not defined in `data`, however, it does not (the button remains unchanged).

Comment: It may also be better to make each row of the table into its own component. That way, the button and the row state will both be part of the same component and you won't need a global array.

Comment: it is explained in the first section of the [Object Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats) doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an object, you have to use `Vue.set` (or `this.$set`). See [Reactivity In Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) from the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Vue js doesn't allow you to access arrays directly. See the documentation at https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

Instead of using

```
this.rowState[rowID] = newValue;
```

You should use

```
rowState.$set(rowID, newValue)
```

or

```
rowState.splice(rowID, 1, newValue).
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I feel it answered his question at least as well as the accepted answer.